# Wordpress - using Ajax on Woocommerce add to cart button shortcodes

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a pretty strange problem with a custom build I am doing in Wordpress. I am using hooks to overwrite a starter theme's 'add-to-cart' button on a custom page showing products. The weird thing is that when I loop through the add-to-cart button to add quantity options on my products, the original Ajax function disappears. I then implemented another function to add it back in (and cause my custom 'view cart' button's items-in-cart number to update) but although it works in the cart, it doesn't seem to be working for my custom shop page.

I am using this snippet in my header to handle the cart contents:

```
<?php if ( in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) ) {

$count = WC()->cart->cart_contents_count;
?><a class="cart-contents" href="<?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_url(); ?>" title="<?php _e( 'View your shopping cart' ); ?>"><?php 
if ( $count > 0 ) {
    ?>
    <span class="cart-contents-count"><?php echo esc_html( $count ); ?></span>
    <?php
}
    ?></a>
```

And here are my two functions in my child-theme functions.php:

```
/**
 * Ensure cart contents update when products are added to the cart via AJAX
*/

function my_header_add_to_cart_fragment( $fragments ) {

ob_start();
$count = WC()->cart->cart_contents_count;
?><a class="cart-contents" href="<?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_url(); ?>" title="<?php _e( 'View your shopping cart' ); ?>"><?php
if ( $count > 0 ) {
    ?>
    <span class="cart-contents-count"><?php echo esc_html( $count ); ?></span>
    <?php            
}
    ?></a><?php

$fragments['a.cart-contents'] = ob_get_clean();

return $fragments;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'my_header_add_to_cart_fragment' );


/**
 * Add quantity to products in Products Page
 */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'quantity_inputs_for_woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 10, 2 );

function quantity_inputs_for_woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link( $html, $product ) {
if ( $product && $product->is_type( 'simple' ) && $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() && ! $product->is_sold_individually() ) {
    $html = '<form action="' . esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ) . '" class="cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
    $html .= woocommerce_quantity_input( array(), $product, false );
    $html .= '<button type="submit" class="button alt">' . esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() ) . '</button>';
    $html .= '</form>';
}
return $html;
}
```

I think that my second function adding a new add-to-cart button is overwriting the initial Ajax functionality, but everything I try to do to add this functionality back in is not working. I'm not the best at JS/jQuery so it's probably that I'm not implementing my code properly.

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Need to add another classes to the button i.e **add_to_cart_button** & **ajax_add_to_cart**.
Hope this will do for you.

Comment: Thank you Tristup, but I've tried to add the classes and it's not working. I've tried applying them as filters to the loop and I've also tried adding them as HTML classes appended to the button...Am I missing something here?